# IndexError: list index out of range in sys

Tags: python, index-error

In this line of code, I get that type of error
How can I fix it

```
import sys

op = sys.argv[1]
t = sys.argv[2] 
x = sys.argv[3]
y = sys.argv[4]
if len(sys.argv) >= 5 else 0
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: + command you used to start your program with.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

`1` isn't the first element, so either you meant with `>` (not `>=`):

```
import sys

op = sys.argv[1]

t = sys.argv[2]

x = sys.argv[3]

y = sys.argv[4] if len(sys.argv) > 5 else 0
```

Or with starting index 0:

```
import sys

op = sys.argv[0]

t = sys.argv[1]

x = sys.argv[2]

y = sys.argv[3] if len(sys.argv) >= 5 else 0
```